# Cell matrix (changing size in matlab)

Tags: matlab

How can a matrix as A

```
       [1x11 double]    [1x11 double]    [1x6 double]
A =    [1x14 double]    [1x10 double]    [1x8 double]
```

be cnverted to a matrix ,say B,

```
B =    [1x25 double]    [1x21 double]    [1x14 double]
```

[] blocks in B matrix contains elements in rows of matrix A. Any answers is highly apreciated.

Answer (score 1):

One of many possible solutions,

```
B = cell(1,size(A,2));
for i = 1:numel(B)
   B{i} = [A{:,i}];
end
```

Comment: Is 2 in the first line of the code equal to number of rows in A?

Comment: consider to take a look at the documentation of [size](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/size.html): `szdim = size(A,dim)` returns the length of dimension dim.